# Error:(88, 46) error: cannot access TintableBackgroundView class file for androidx.core.view.TintableBackgroundView not found

Tags: android

I working on android suddenly I get this error:

```
Error:(88, 46) error: cannot access TintableBackgroundView
class file for androidx.core.view.TintableBackgroundView was not found
```

Kindly help me, please if I remove this another error occur version parceable

```
configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'androidx.core', module: 'core'
    }
```

This is my `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.muhammadtehmoor.guardian_module"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude '**/language/bm/*'
    }
}



dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible,GradleCompatible
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.6'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.3.1'
    //implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:1.1@aar'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.7'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:0.8.2'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0'
    implementation 'io.paperdb:paperdb:2.6'
    implementation 'me.spark:submitbutton:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.alimuzaffar.lib:animated-edit-text:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'androidx.core', module: 'core'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is my `build.gradle` (project level)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'


    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
                 url "https://maven.google.com"
              }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/spark/maven'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost every library now, have migrated to `AndroidX` and your project seems to be still using Support Libraries, plus you are removing the `:core` of `androidx` which might be a dependency of some other library.

You should migrate to `AndroidX` now.